# submit form withour refreshing whole page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I am making a URL shortener with react and when I send a request to get a shortened URL, the whole page reloads and then I get my shortened URL. I tried to use *preventDefault()* but it doesn't work.

**App.js**

```js
handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    if(this.state.value == ''){
      toast.error('enter valid url')
    }
    await saveUrl({ url: this.state.value })
  }
...
render() { 
    return ( 
      <React.Fragment>
        <InputForm 
          onChange={this.handleChange} 
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        />
        <Urls onDelete={this.handleDelete} urls={this.state.urls}/>
      </React.Fragment>
     );
  }
```

**urls.jsx**

```js
class InputForm extends Component {
    state = { 
        value: '',
        text: ""
    }


    render() { 
        return ( 
            <form className="url-input" onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>
                <input type='text' name='url'  onChange={this.props.onChange}  placeholder="Shorten a link here..."/>
                <button id="shorten" className="btn">Shorten It!</button>
             </form>
         );
    }
}
```

Comment: You meant `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Yes i meant ```e.preventDefault()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When submitting a form it will go to the location defined in `action=""`. The form values will be sent via POST as URL parameters. If no action is defined, the form will post the values to the same path (`./`).

You can use `type="button"` on your button to prevent the form submit.

If you do so, you have to implement a custom action on button click. Most likely via `onclick="myFormsubmitHandler()"` and process the form values by yourself.

=> `<button type="button" onclick="myFormSubmitHandler()">Submit</button>`

happy coding!

Comment: And what should i write in myFormsubmitHandler function?

Comment: @ზურაკურტანიძე Depends on what you are planning to do with your form values. As far as i can see you already have an `onSubmit` function that you are atm calling on form submit. You could instead call the same function on button click.

Comment: oh, i understand, Danke